# WCF: Single operation fails with MessageSecurityException

Tags: wcf

So what we have here is a fairly trivial WCF service with a bunch of operations. Now, all but one operation work just fine, but that single one fails with `MessageSecurityException`.

This particular method is just like any other method in this particular service: no fancy authentication or authorization attributes, no impersonation, no nothing. Just plain hit-the-DB-and-return-results kind of method. Security is set up as follows:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Yet whenever it gets invoked, it fails with

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'

I know this is a very open-ended question, but I hope someone has experienced the same.

Comment: Do all the methods, including the ones that work, use the same binding and security configuration? Do you get anything likely looking from WCF tracing and/or message logging?

Comment: @shambulator Wait, is this possible to have different security configurations for different methods in _one_ service?

Comment: I guess that answers my question :) Security is per binding, which means you could have multiple endpoints each exposing different methods (using separate contracts) and with different bindings. But I'm guessing that by "one service", you also mean "one endpoint", with one contract and *all* the methods.